# Angular Hide With Button

Tags: html, angular, typescript, show-hide

So I'm working with Angular and I'm trying to make a button that when clicked disappears. I have tried to use `[hidden]`, `(click)="showHide = !showHide"`, and a bunch of other methods. Nothing is working so far.

My html (currently):

```html
<div class="rows">
   <div class="a-bunch-of-styles-for-my-button">
      <a type="button" class="more-styles" (click)="inboundClick = !inboundClick" [routerLink]="['/inbound']" href="">
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my component:

```
export class AppComponent {
   inboundClick = false;
}
```

In essence I have 2 buttons on a page and when one button is clicked I want to hide both buttons and display a set of new buttons.

I'm very new to Angular and I'm very confused why this won't work.

Comment: you have a spelling mistake in the component: `flase` should be `false`. Could you include the template for the buttons that you wish to display/hide as well in your question

Comment: @0mpurdy its not spelled wrong in the actual code.

Comment: Ok, just checking :) It may also be worth trying to replicate the problem in a plunk [here's a template](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5). The best directive for hiding would probably be `*ngIf` - [here's a tutorial](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/directives/ng_if_directive.html)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your HTML

```
<div class="yourCssClass" *ngIf="this.isButtonVisible" (click)="this.isButtonVisible = false">
...
</div>
```

Your TypeScript

```
export class AppComponent {
   private isButtonVisible = true;
}
```

This should do the job. `*ngIf` automatically hides the element, if the condition evaluates `false`, so setting the variable to `false` is sufficient.

The problem I see here is, that you don't control the visibility at any point. Using [ngClass] to add a specific class, if a condition is met, or `*ngIf` is helpful, whenever you try to change elements on user interaction.

For more information on `[ngClass]`, you can read about its usage here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

You can read about `*ngIf` here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Especially the "Common Use" part should be interesting for you.

**Edit:**
Reading your comment below it seems you did not notice what `[hidden]` and `(click)` actually do. `[hidden]` controls the visibility of the element, usually dependent on a certain condition. `(click)` however is a quick way to bind a Click-Event to your element.

Using both of those tools enables to hide an element, by changing a variable, if a user clicks on your element (the new value of the variable may be assigned by a function called by `(click)` or inline, as demonstrated in the example code).

**Edit2:** Yep, you meant Angular2/4 ;) So this should do the job.

Comment: Angular now references all versions of Angular above 2.0.0 and AngualrJS refers to all versions before that. so in fact im working with Angular 4 but its similar to 2 and uses the same name now.

Comment: this also works really well. is there a way to do a bring the element back?

Comment: Yes! *ngIf will not hide the element, if the condition evaluates `true`, so setting the variable `isButtonVisible` to `true` is sufficient. Just change the `(click)` event code to a toggle function like `(click)="this.isButtonVisible = !this.isButtonVisible"`. However, you can set the variable wherever you want (this can be another button like a Reset-Button).

Comment: @RaptorJesus I just remembered that there is another important difference between `*ngIf` and `[hidden]`. While `[hidden]` sets the element to `display: none` thus making it invisible, using `*ngIf` **removes** the element from the DOM, resetting it's state when displayed again. For instance, if you hide a scrollable list of messages using `*ngIf` and its condition becomes `true` later, you end up at the start again, as if you loaded it for the first time. `[hidden]` avoids this afaik, as it just hides the element, but it's "still there".

Comment: There is a huge difference between `hidden` and `*ngIf`. Former is the way to go if target's visibility will be toggled a lot, latter otherwise. While in this case `*ngIf*` could be the best practise, I feel the accepted answer should at least mention `hidden` property as it's what title contains and therefore a keyword leading other readers here.

Answer (score 12):

Here is how you can achieve that:

> In your component.html:

```
<a type="button" class="more-styles" 
   [hidden]="!inboundClick" 
   (click)="inboundClick = !inboundClick" 
   [routerLink]="['/inbound']" href="">
</a>

<a type="button" class="more-styles" 
   [hidden]="!outboundClick " 
   (click)="outboundClick = !outboundClick " 
   [routerLink]="['/outbound']" href="">
</a>
```

> ... and in your AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent {
    inboundClick = true;
    outboundClick = true;
}
```

---

[**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BGIQZV7V69pYUPuO2sFV?p=preview)

Comment: this worked perfectly. i didn't realize that you had to use [hidden] and (click) at the same time. lastly could you flip it around with a different variable in the component to show it again if a different button was clicked?

Comment: check this plunker link I created: https://plnkr.co/edit/BGIQZV7V69pYUPuO2sFV?p=preview

Comment: @RaptorJesus why downvoted? The solution works as per your requirements. Strange :/

Comment: sorry mate, your answer does work, but after more research *ngif is the preferred method. [hidden] is generally considered to be avoided if possible. and after more work i do need to remove the object from the DOM, which is what *Ngif does. ill put the vote back up because it did work.

Comment: thanks, my answer was based on your question description, thats why I used `[hidden]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat way to hide/remove items, specially handy if there is a list of items.

Note how it takes advantage of [Angular's template variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) (`#ListItem`).

So your template can either be something like:

```html
<a type="button" #ButtonA
   (click)="onClick(ButtonA)" 
   [routerLink]="['/inbound']" href="">
</a>

<a type="button" #ButtonB
   (click)="onClick(ButtonB)" 
   [routerLink]="['/outbound']" href="">
</a>
```

Or like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
  <div #ListItem>
    <button (click)="onClick(ListItem)">
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Depending on how you want to hide - if you want to remove it from DOM, or just hide it with CSS. And depending if you want to toggle it or just remove it completely. There are a few options:

**Remove element from DOM** (no way to get it back):

```js
close(e: HTMLElement) {
   e.remove();
}
```

**Hiding it** with the [hidden attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) - beware that the hidden attribute can be overriden by CSS, it will happen if you are changing the `display` property and the rule has more precedence:

```js
close(e: HTMLElement) {
   e.toggleAttribute('hidden');
}
```

**Hiding it "manually"** with CSS:

```js
close(e: HTMLElement) {
   e.classList.toggle('hide-element');
}
```

```css
.hide-element {
   display: none;
}
```